# sparse - Fixing build warnings

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm compiling the [sparse](https://sparse.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) - linux kernel checking tool.

But it throws the following warning:

> lovegcy@knltest-VirtualBox:~/git_root/sparse$ make
>        GEN      version.h
>   **/bin/sh: 1: llvm-config: not found**
>   **Makefile:63: Your system does not have libxml, disabling c2xml
>
>   Makefile:75: Your system does not have libgtk2, disabling test-inspect
>
>   Makefile:79: Your system does not have llvm, disabling sparse-llvm**
>        CC       test-lexing.o
>        CC       target.o
>        CC       parse.o
>        CC       tokenize.o
>        CC       pre-process.o
>        CC       symbol.o
>        CC       lib.o
>        CC       scope.o
>        CC       expression.o
>        CC       show-parse.o
>        CC       evaluate.o
>        CC       expand.o
>        CC       inline.o
>        CC       linearize.o
>        CC       char.o
>        CC       sort.o
>        CC       allocate.o
>        CC       compat-linux.o
>        CC       ptrlist.o
>        CC       flow.o
>        CC       cse.o
>        CC       simplify.o
>        CC       memops.o
>        CC       liveness.o
>        CC       storage.o
>        CC       unssa.o
>        CC       dissect.o
>        AR       libsparse.a
>        LINK     test-lexing
>        CC       test-parsing.o
>        LINK     test-parsing
>        CC       obfuscate.o
>        LINK     obfuscate
>        CC       compile.o
>        CC       compile-i386.o
>   compile-i386.c: In function ‘emit_insn_atom’:
>   **compile-i386.c:719:7: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]**
>        LINK     compile
>        CC       graph.o
>        LINK     graph
>        CC       sparse.o
>        LINK     sparse
>        CC       test-linearize.o
>        LINK     test-linearize
>        CC       example.o
>        LINK     example
>        CC       test-unssa.o
>        LINK     test-unssa
>        CC       test-dissect.o
>        LINK     test-dissect
>        CC       ctags.o
>        LINK     ctags
>        GEN      sparse.pc

Fix the following
Makefile:63: Your system does not have libxml, disabling c2xml
Makefile:75: Your system does not have libgtk2, disabling test-inspect

**by:**

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libgtk2.0-dev
```

For

> /bin/sh: 1: llvm-config: not found
>   Makefile:79: Your system does not have llvm, disabling sparse-llvm

the llvm-3.2-dev is installed, but it is still there.

I still donot know how to fix the following warning too:

> compile-i386.c: In function ‘emit_insn_atom’:
>   compile-i386.c:719:7: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]

Could anyone give some suggestions?

Thank you very much!

---

**Update** : Following  [TheCodeArtist's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18139577/319204), here is the build error log after llvm installed.

```
lovegcy@knltest-VirtualBox:~/git_root/sparse$ make
CC test-lexing.o
CC target.o
CC parse.o
CC tokenize.o
CC pre-process.o
CC symbol.o
CC lib.o
CC scope.o
CC expression.o
CC show-parse.o
CC evaluate.o
CC expand.o
CC inline.o
CC linearize.o
CC char.o
CC sort.o
CC allocate.o
CC compat-linux.o
CC ptrlist.o
CC flow.o
CC cse.o
CC simplify.o
CC memops.o
CC liveness.o
CC storage.o
CC unssa.o
CC dissect.o
AR libsparse.a
LINK test-lexing
CC test-parsing.o
LINK test-parsing
CC obfuscate.o
LINK obfuscate
CC compile.o
CC compile-i386.o
compile-i386.c: In function ‘emit_insn_atom’:
compile-i386.c:719:7: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
LINK compile
CC graph.o
LINK graph
CC sparse.o
LINK sparse
CC test-linearize.o
LINK test-linearize
CC example.o
LINK example
CC test-unssa.o
LINK test-unssa
CC test-dissect.o
LINK test-dissect
CC ctags.o
LINK ctags
CC c2xml.o
LINK c2xml
CC test-inspect.o
CC ast-model.o
CC ast-view.o
CC ast-inspect.o
LINK test-inspect
CC sparse-llvm.o
LINK sparse-llvm
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Signals.o): In function PrintStackTrace(void*)':
(.text+0x74): undefined reference todladdr'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Signals.o): In function PrintStackTrace(void*)':
(.text+0x1fe): undefined reference todladdr'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Mutex.o): In function llvm::sys::MutexImpl::MutexImpl(bool)':
(.text+0x58): undefined reference topthread_mutexattr_init'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Mutex.o): In function llvm::sys::MutexImpl::MutexImpl(bool)':
(.text+0x64): undefined reference topthread_mutexattr_settype'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Mutex.o): In function llvm::sys::MutexImpl::MutexImpl(bool)':
(.text+0x74): undefined reference topthread_mutexattr_setpshared'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Mutex.o): In function llvm::sys::MutexImpl::MutexImpl(bool)':
(.text+0x88): undefined reference topthread_mutexattr_destroy'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Mutex.o): In function llvm::sys::MutexImpl::tryacquire()':
(.text+0x179): undefined reference topthread_mutex_trylock'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::RWMutexImpl()':
(.text+0x3e): undefined reference topthread_rwlock_init'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::~RWMutexImpl()':
(.text+0x80): undefined reference topthread_rwlock_destroy'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::reader_acquire()':
(.text+0xb9): undefined reference topthread_rwlock_rdlock'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::reader_release()':
(.text+0xe9): undefined reference topthread_rwlock_unlock'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::writer_acquire()':
(.text+0x119): undefined reference topthread_rwlock_wrlock'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::writer_release()':
(.text+0x149): undefined reference topthread_rwlock_unlock'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.o): In function llvm::sys::ThreadLocalImpl::~ThreadLocalImpl()':
(.text+0x25): undefined reference topthread_key_delete'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.o): In function llvm::sys::ThreadLocalImpl::ThreadLocalImpl()':
(.text+0xae): undefined reference topthread_key_create'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.o): In function llvm::sys::ThreadLocalImpl::setInstance(void const*)':
(.text+0xe2): undefined reference topthread_setspecific'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.o): In function llvm::sys::ThreadLocalImpl::getInstance()':
(.text+0x10a): undefined reference topthread_getspecific'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Threading.o): In function llvm::llvm_execute_on_thread(void (*)(void*), void*, unsigned int)':
(.text+0x1c2): undefined reference topthread_create'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Threading.o): In function llvm::llvm_execute_on_thread(void (*)(void*), void*, unsigned int)':
(.text+0x1da): undefined reference topthread_join'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Threading.o): In function llvm::llvm_execute_on_thread(void (*)(void*), void*, unsigned int)':
(.text+0x20c): undefined reference topthread_attr_setstacksize'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: * [sparse-llvm] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Properly installing llvm :

During the build, for **`make`** to detect `llvm` on the system ,`llvm-config` is required to be installed on your system properly. On Ubuntu, the following command will download(~16MB packages) and install all the dependencies correctly

```
$ sudo apt-get install llvm
```

Download the latest source of sparse

```
$ git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/devel/sparse/sparse.git
```

Build and install sparse

```
$ cd sparse
$ make
$ make install
```

(**Tested on Ubuntu 10.04**)

---

#### Fixing the innocuous Warning :

The following error is harmless in the current context as we are not concerned with the result of the call to `write()` at **line 719** of **compile-i386.c**

```
compile-i386.c:719:7: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
```

Fixing this error is as simple as modifying **line 719** of **compile-i386.c** to

```
comment[0] = write(STDOUT_FILENO, s, strlen(s));
```

This warning is triggered during build due to the `-Wall` (Enable ALL warnings) flag passed to gcc at **line 16** of the **Makefile**

`CFLAGS += -Wall -Wwrite-strings`

Comment: Thanks TheCodeArtist. I tried your suggestion to install llvm. But it throws more errors there. The install log is appended in question.

Comment: Sorry I can't append the build log into question so I add it in the following answer section. Thanks again.

Comment: Updated my answer with exact details/steps to download and build sparse successfully.